# Display markers of multiple devices by only updating the specific device's marker without changing other markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, marker

I have got multiple devices sending GPS data every minute. Each device has MAC address and can identify that particular device has send the data. So, whenever devices send the GPS data event will happen and below code will run. It also displays the marker.

```
sock.onmessage = function(evt){
         var data = JSON.parse(evt.data);
         var latlng = data.GPS_Data;
         var array = $.map(latlng, function(el) {
            return [[el.lat, el.lng]];
            });
map.addMarker({
             lat:latlng[0].lat,
             lng:latlng[0].lng,
            infoWindow: {
                content: JSON.stringify(data)
            },
            mouseover: function() {
                this.infoWindow.open(this.map, this);
            },
            mouseout: function() {
                this.infoWindow.close();
            }
        });
       }
```

Now , the problem is whenever event happen for the same device for the different location, it will show as different marker rather than removing old marker and adding new one. I know I can remove marker by using `map.removeMarkers();` , but the problem with that is it removes all the markers.

Question: How can I update specific marker with respect to particular MAC address without touching all markers of other devices (whenever event happen for that device) ?

Is there any better way to do this problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds easy: 1. add custom attribute to Marker with MAC value.  2. Put all markers in array/hash. 3. On update, find Marker in array/hash by MAC address.